# App crash while remove object from TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have multiple data in my `UITableView` and when I delete one record.

Comment: Removing the cell implies two steps, one you must remove the data from datasource origin and next make reload tableview or [tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deletePaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView endUpdates];

Comment: Keep that order. And of course don't do it at didEndDisplayingCell, since it's called during the reload, would corrupt the tableview stack

Comment: @teixeiras, i will try & tell you.

Comment: it will crash with this error.. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: did you use deleteRowsAtIndexPaths or the reloadtable

Comment: @teixeiras deleteRowsAtIndexPaths

Comment: @teixeiras, i delete like this         [self.tblVWVideos beginUpdates];
        [self.tblVWVideos deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.tblVWVideos endUpdates];

Comment: So the numberOfRowsInSection is returning the previous number of rows. You must check in the code why is that. Basically, numberOfRowsInSection returns 3, same as before, while was expected to return 2 right before the deleteRowsAtIndexPaths

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `didEndDisplayingCell` to manipulate the cell or the data source array by the passed index path.

It's just a notification ***that the specified cell was removed from the table***

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614870-tableview?language=objc) also states:

> Use this method to detect when a cell is removed from a table view, as opposed to monitoring the view itself to see when it appears or disappears.

The solution is to move the entire code in this method to the location where the cell / data source item is removed and use it **before** removing anything

Comment: which method? i used this -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(FeedSingleViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath ti check cell goes out of screen?

Comment: Exactly **this** method.

Comment: as i mentioned above, app crash while i am fetching object like this in this method.UserVideoObject *objMyUploadedVideo = [arrMyVideos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; Array Contains 2 objects while indexpath returns 0-2

Comment: Please re-read my first sentence in the answer carefully. Don't use the passed index path as an index to get data from the data source array in this method. It's the index path that has gone in that moment.

Comment: i update my question with that method, how to check that?

Comment: can you pls suggest me how to do that?

Comment: you mean to move didEndDisplayingCell code, where i am removing object from array?

Comment: i update my question, if i move this code than pause video will not work.

Comment: Once again, the method `didEndDisplayingCell` is called **after** the cell has been removed from the screen. The passed index path is **not valid**. You have to do your cleanup work **before** removing the cell.

Answer (score -1):

The app is crashing because even though you have deleted the object( so now array will have one less element) but you have not told the table view to reset itself according to new datasource. Even cellforRowAt will crash if you delete the last element. One solution is to reload the tableview by calling:

```
<tableViewName>.reloadData()
```

but it will produce unnecessary flicker if tableViews are quite large and complex. And the Second thing, You should'nt be using didEndDisplayingCell